# GSuite sync to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, google-workspace

I would like to sync GSuite passwords/accounts with onsite Active Directory accounts. I know there is a tool to sync passwords from Active Directory to GSuite, but my organization would like the ability to create/manage users in GSuite and then sync them TO Active Directory or Azure Active Directory. Does anyone know of a tool/platform that allows that type of integration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-made tool to meet your needs currently.

[GCDS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/106368?hl=en) can sync the AD users to GSuite. But you need a reverse.

We can sync GSuite users to AD by following:

- Export the users from GSuite to a csv file.
- Use PowerShell to create/update the Users in AD from a csv file.
- Configure [GCPS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2611859?hl=en) to sync AD users' passwords back up to GSuite.

But after you manage the users in GSuite, you need to perform the above steps on a regular basis.

I know this is not a good way. What I want to say is that your needs are still not implemented at this stage.